# What is the most economical method of taking a MS Access Runtime to Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-access, wine

I've built a program via MS Access 2007 that I distribute via Microsoft Access Runtime. My clients do not have Access. Recently I've received multiple request for the application to be available for Mac. The volume of requests is low enough that it's not economical to rebuild the entire program in another language.

What would be the most economical method of allowing users to use the software on a Mac?

Is LibreOffice or Wine an option in this case, or is the only option for the user to purchase Windows and use a virtual environment?

Answer (score 2):

**LibreOffice Base:** *Extremely* unlikely. Even if you were to get Base to connect to the Access tables it almost certainly would not be able to use the Access forms, reports, macros, VBA code, etc..

**Wine:** Worth a try, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if there were issues, quite possibly serious ones. According to the WineHQ page [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25162), Access 2010 gets a "Bronze" compatibility rating, meaning

> Application works, but it has some issues, even for normal use; a game may not redraw properly or display fonts in wrong colours, be much slower than it should etc.

That same page lists "Visual Basic" as one of the things that did *not* work under Wine when it was last tested.

If I were you I would give the latest version of Wine a quick try to see if things have improved but I wouldn't spend more than a couple of hours tinkering with it. I suspect that a Virtual Machine running an actual copy of Windows is probably the only real option in this case.